# How to put variable value in a href?

Tags: php, variables, get, href

This question may sound banal, but I'm really new to php. I have:

```
<?php $kzl="pencho"; ?>

<a href="settings.php?var=$kzl">asdf</a>
```

in the script settings.php

```
<? echo &_GET['var']; ?>
```

and on the screen is printed kzl not the value in kzl, why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to print value of `$kzl` in url. Use this;

```
<a href="settings.php?var=<?php echo $kzl;?>">asdf</a>
```

Or you can use;

```
echo '<a href="settings.php?var=' . $kzl . '">asdf</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are not doing it the right way.

Do it:

```
 <a href="settings.php?var=<?php echo $kzl;?>">asdf</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call variable in PHP Block

```
<a href="settings.php?var=<?php echo $kzl; ?>">asdf</a>
```

Comment: It would be better to check already posted answers before posting your own